Upgrading Terraform via Nix
I am trying to upgrade a really old Nix environment which we use to roll-out changes to our infrastructure with terraform.
I do not want to upgrade to the latest terraform version, as Hashicorp introduced a new license with version 1.6.
I have located the right nix-package for terraform 1.5.7 (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/37cac5f032f6da598eddde8dd49eb7a820d72ea3.tar.gz), which indeed upgrades terraform.
Where I run into problems is with the installation of the terraform providers.
Changes in the configuration are a new archive url and pkgs.terraform_1_0.withPlugins was changed into pkgs.terraform.withPlugin
let
    pkgs = ( import (builtins.fetchTarball {
         url = "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/37cac5f032f6da598eddde8dd49eb7a820d72ea3.tar.gz";
        })) {};
in
pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
      ...
    (pkgs.terraform.withPlugins (p: [
      (pkgs.callPackage ./terraform-provider-kafka.nix {})
      (pkgs.callPackage ./terraform-provider-confluent-schema-registry.nix {})
      p.null
      p.azurerm
      p.external
      p.sops
    ]))
  ];
}

The configuration of the terraform-provider-kafka.nix and terraform-provider-confluent-schema-registry.nix have not changed. terraform-provider-kafka.nix looks like this (terraform-provider-confluent-schema-registry.nix is very similar):
{ lib, fetchFromGitHub, buildGoModule }:
buildGoModule rec {
  pname = "terraform-provider-kafka";
  version = "0.5.0";

  src = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "Mongey";
    repo = "terraform-provider-kafka";
    rev = "v${version}";
    sha256 = "0ha52lyjmq5sfqh6ar657bgybsrprnmglljsc7rmfqi6w05689nm";
  };
  vendorSha256 = "14978wq9w56hk7b5agmgb44akbdqmqq1i0z7wlhray7z78w1q1zb";

  postBuild = "mv $NIX_BUILD_TOP/go/bin/terraform-provider-kafka{,_v${version}}";
  meta = with lib; {
    description = "A Terraform provider for managing kafka topics and acls";
    homepage = "https://github.com/Mongey/terraform-provider-kafka";
    license = licenses.mit;
    maintainers = with maintainers; [ jterwoerds ];
  };
}

When I call nix-shell, everything looks okay.
Building subPackage ./kafka
Building subPackage ./tls-debug
Building subPackage ./tools
package github.com/Mongey/terraform-provider-kafka/tools: build constraints exclude all Go files in /tmp/nix-build-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0.drv-0/source/tools
running tests
ok      github.com/Mongey/terraform-provider-kafka/kafka        0.776s
installing
post-installation fixup
shrinking RPATHs of ELF executables and libraries in /nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0
shrinking /nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0/bin/terraform-provider-kafka_v0.5.0
shrinking /nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0/bin/tls-debug
checking for references to /tmp/nix-build-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0.drv-0/ in /nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0...
patching script interpreter paths in /nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0
stripping (with command strip and flags -S -p) in  /nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0/bin
building '/nix/store/ai1csswcyn09phza8wx8z8f0ac7d3197-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0-go-modules.drv'...
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/gq10cv4ih0vkfyi0lv7ablancigqg7ya-source
source root is source
patching sources
updateAutotoolsGnuConfigScriptsPhase
configuring
building
...
installing
building '/nix/store/y1s3rp1qs5rcvja3aa5qh91bpm216shr-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0.drv'...
unpacking sources
unpacking source archive /nix/store/gq10cv4ih0vkfyi0lv7ablancigqg7ya-source
source root is source
patching sources
updateAutotoolsGnuConfigScriptsPhase
configuring
building
Building subPackage .
Building subPackage ./schemaregistry
running tests
no Makefile or custom checkPhase, doing nothing
installing
post-installation fixup
shrinking RPATHs of ELF executables and libraries in /nix/store/1n8y9n37yyn08rj72wmg4jm6r305nknk-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0
shrinking /nix/store/1n8y9n37yyn08rj72wmg4jm6r305nknk-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0/bin/terraform-provider-schema-registry_v0.8.0
checking for references to /tmp/nix-build-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0.drv-0/ in /nix/store/1n8y9n37yyn08rj72wmg4jm6r305nknk-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0...
patching script interpreter paths in /nix/store/1n8y9n37yyn08rj72wmg4jm6r305nknk-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0
stripping (with command strip and flags -S -p) in  /nix/store/1n8y9n37yyn08rj72wmg4jm6r305nknk-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0/bin
building '/nix/store/5dwi1ww4k6c24lcr57qvrcc2gfq2yvi8-terraform-1.5.7.drv'...


find: '/nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0/libexec/terraform-providers': No such file or directory
find: '/nix/store/1n8y9n37yyn08rj72wmg4jm6r305nknk-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0/libexec/terraform-providers': No such file or directory


But in the end I get the "No such file or directory" error.
find: '/nix/store/jnp74cfssq1dm25lm6n6sdb97592s6mg-terraform-provider-kafka-0.5.0/libexec/terraform-providers': No such file or directory
find: '/nix/store/1n8y9n37yyn08rj72wmg4jm6r305nknk-terraform-provider-schema-registry-0.8.0/libexec/terraform-providers': No such file or directory

What causes this error, and how can I fix it?
